# Husband & wife twice - coincidence?

Tags: casting, argo, halt-and-catch-fire

I just re-watched *[Argo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/reference)* (2012) after not having seen it in quite a while. In the meantime, I've watched the series *[Halt and Catch Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire_(TV_series))* (2014–17). So I couldn't help noticing that Scoot McNairy and Kerry Bishé play husband & wife in both. I'm not aware of any other connection between this movie and that TV show, and these two don't seem to be married in real life or anything, so what gives? It's especially interesting because, in both cases, McNairy is playing a dorky guy who seems to be punching well above his weight, spouse-wise. Both of these couples are a bit hard to accept, at first glance.

Is there some reason that these two play a married couple in both these stories? Is it purely coincidence?

Comment: No connection just pointing it out,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to just be a co-incidence:

> Q: Both you and Kerry Bishé appeared in Argo. Were you surprised to see her again on the Halt and Catch Fire set?
>
> A: I had a great time working with her on Argo. I was really excited to see her and to work with her again, on another show, and to play her husband.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://www.amc.com/shows/halt-and-catch-fire/talk/2014/06/halt-and-catch-fire-qa-scoot-mcnairy-gordon-clark)</sup>

and

> AX: Do you know if you were cast together as a couple – that is, had anybody in the casting process seen you together in ARGO – or how did that work?
>
> BISHE: It was just a happy coincidence.
>
> McNAIRY: Yeah. I’m not a hundred percent [certain].
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.assignmentx.com/2015/halt-and-catch-fire-stars-kerry-bishe-and-scoot-mcnairy-on-season-2-exclusive-interview/)</sup>

McNairy and Bishé also appeared together in a Marvel One Shot short on *Thor: Dark World* DVD/Blu-ray so there's another on the list. :)